# React Native Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a little problem in my code in React Native, the error says ***Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0*** , I just want to update the existing password with new password.

```
  const getProfile = async(token) =>{
    let jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    jsonValue = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
    setProfile(jsonValue);
    console.log(config.API_URL + '/users/'+ jsonValue.userId)
    fetch(config.API_URL + '/users/'+ jsonValue.userId, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) =>  response.json().then(data=>({status:response.status, body:data})) )
    .then((response) => {
    console.log("User information = ",response);
    if(response.status==200)
        {
          if(response.body.length > 0)
          {         
            let _UserData = {};
            setUserData(response.body[0]);
            setUserPassword(decodeURI(response.body[0].Password))
            console.log("response.body[0]",response.body[0]);
          }else{
            setErrortext(response.body.msg);
            setPreventSubmit(true);
          }
        }else{
          setErrortext(response.body.msg);
          setPreventSubmit(true);
        };
      })
    }


const handleSubmit = async(valuesToSubmit) =>  {

let finalValidationPassed=true;
if(valuesToSubmit['password1'] == valuesToSubmit['password2'] & valuesToSubmit['password2'] == valuesToSubmit.userdata){
    let _data = {
      UsersId: UserData.UsersId,

      Password:  valuesToSubmit.userdata
    }
    console.log("_data",_data)
    if(finalValidationPassed)
    {
       setErrortext("");
       fetch(config.API_URL + '/user/password', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(_data),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) =>  response.json().then(data=>({status:response.status, body:data})) )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("data",response);
        if(response.status==200){
          setIsEdit(false);
          alert("Profile Updated!");
          refetch();
        }else{
          setErrortext(response.body[0]?.msg);
          setErrortext(response.body[0]?._msgerror);
        }
      }); 

    }else{
      alert("Error");
    }
  
}else{
  alert("Sorry, submission failed. Please check your data entries.");
}

}


      <Formik
         enableReinitialize
         initialValues={{userdata:UserData.Password, password1: "", password2: "" }}
          onSubmit={(values) =>{ handleSubmit(values)}}
        >
        {(props) => (
  
  <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
    <Text>CURRENT PASSWORD</Text>
      <TextInput
            name="Password"
            value={props.values.userdata}
            style={formStyles.inputStyle}
            underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
            placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={props.handleChange('userdata')}
      />
    </View>
    {(props.errors.Password && props.touched.Password) && <Text style={formStyles.errorText}>{errors.Password}</Text> }
    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <Text>SET NEW PASSWORD</Text>
      <TextInput
            name="password1"
            value={props.values.password1}
            style={formStyles.inputStyle}
            underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
            placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onChangeText={props.handleChange("password1")}
      />
    </View>
    {(props.errors.Password && props.touched.Password) && <Text style={formStyles.errorText}>{errors.Password}</Text> }
    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <Text>CONFIRM NEW PASSWORD</Text>
      <TextInput
            name="password2"
            value={props.values.password2}
            style={formStyles.inputStyle}
            underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
            placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onChangeText={props.handleChange("password2")}
      />
    </View>
    {(props.errors.Password && props.touched.Password) && <Text style={formStyles.errorText}>{errors.Password}</Text> }
    <TouchableOpacity
style={formStyles.buttonStyle}
activeOpacity={0.5}
disabled={!props.isValid}
onPress={props.handleSubmit}
>
      <Text style={formStyles.buttonTextStyle}>RESET PASSWORD</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </SafeAreaView>
)}
      </Formik>
```

this is the return from api

[image]

this is the error i recieved from the console.log

***Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0***

the error is pointing here

[image]

console.log("_data", _data)

[image]

this is the response from the api

[image]

API

```
async function updateUserPassword(req, res, next){
    params = req.body;//post
    let validation_rules = {
        UsersId:'required|integer',
        Password: 'required'
    }
    console.log("validation_rules",validation_rules);
    let validation = new Validator(params, validation_rules);
    if(validation.passes())
    {
        try
        {
            let resultsplayer = await userprofile.getProfile(params)
            if(resultsplayer.rowCount > 0){
                let results = await userprofile.updateUserPassword(params)
                if(results.rowCount > 0){
                    res.status(200).json(results.rows);
                }else{
                    res.status(304).json({"message":"Update Failed"});
                }
            }else{
                res.status(404).json({"message":"Record Not Found"});
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log("-----result data error-----\n", err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }else{
        res.status(400).json(validation.errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this error pointing to this line? `jsonValue = JSON.parse(jsonValue);`

Comment: I'll check, please wait

Comment: ` fetch(config.API_URL + '/user/password', {`

Comment: can you show the output to "console.log(_data)". I think _data is not a JSON which is why JSON.stringify(_data) is throwing an error

Comment: i've posted the result of `console.log("_data", _data)`

Comment: Sounds like the API is returning HTML not JSON

Comment: so if the api is returning html, what should i do or put in the JSON? @RichardBarker

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong here. The API shouldn't be returning HTML. If you are trying to interact with some normal HTML page (not a Web API that returns JSON) you'll need to manually extract the data from the returned HTML, which is not something I'd recommend (though possible and sometimes perfectly "does the job"). If you have control over the server that you are sending the request to, change it to return the response data as JSON instead of an HTML page (make sure you don't try to display that same data in a web page if you were displaying, as it'd fail).

Comment: The API may very well return HTML when an error is encountered and server can serve up both. I've encountered this issue too many times. It could also be XML. You should be `.catch`ing the error and handling the data another way when the error is thrown.

Comment: I just updated my code, please see